# Pagination in M Query for a REST API

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I'm quite new to M and Power Query in general so I'm having a hard time understanding other peoples solutions to similar problems.

But I need help in writing an M query for a REST API which returns one Record called PagerInfo and one List of Records called Sites. I want to convert the list of records to a table and then expand the table. I need pagination for the query where the size limit is called take and is limited to 1000 rows. The total number of rows is stated in the PagerInfo. You can also add skip in the url to skip a set amount of rows.

My query looks like this but this obviously only returns the first 10000 rows and does not continue after that. So I need help with possibly a loop that ends when the records returned are less than the take.

```
let
    url = "my base url",
    endpoint = "/sites",
    take = 10000,
    response = Web.Contents(url & endpoint & "?take=" & Text.From(take)),
    json = Json.Document(response),
    pagerInfo = json[PagerInfo],
    sites = json[Sites],
    table = Table.FromList(sites, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, Record.FieldNames),
    expandedTable = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(table, "Column1", Record.FieldNames(table{0}[Column1]))
in
    expandedTable
```

Any help or tips are appreciated.

Comment: https://gorilla.bi/power-query/list-generate-api-calls/